# Change color when hover a font awesome icon?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-4

Base in the Font Awesome [documentation](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked) I create this icon:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

This code create this html:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x">::before</i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">::before</i>
</span>
```

It is a stacked Flag icon. I want to change the icon color on Hover event, I tried with all these:

```
.fa-stack:hover{
color: red
}
.fa-stack i:hover{
color: red
}
.fa-stack i before:hover{
color: red
}
```

but not working.

Comment: it should be color: red;

Comment: Check your CSS syntax

Comment: was a typo but problem is still there

Answer (score 79, accepted):

if you want to change only the colour of the flag on `hover` use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uvamhedx/

```css
.fa-flag:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-flag fa-3x"></i>
```

Comment: And using ***Font Awesome 5*** ? https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/js/all.js

Comment: @Kiquenet do you have codepen or jsffiddle with your issue?

Answer (score 7):

use - !important - to override default black

```css
.fa-heart:hover{
   color:red !important;
}
.fa-heart-o:hover{
   color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-2x"></i>
```

Comment: Is `!important` is really necessary? Many consider it as anti-pattern in programming.

Comment: using Important is not a good solution since it cannot be overwritten. You can overwrite all non inline css using specificity

Comment: I had to use !important to get this to work, unfortunately, but the icon was also within an ag-Grid, if that means anything. For an Angular project, I also had to put it in the styles.css file - it would not work in the component.css

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is this, example:

HTML:

```html
<span class="close_form">
  <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
</span>
```

CSS:

```css
.fa-circle {
  color: #d7d7d710;
  transition: 500ms;
}
    
.close_form:hover .fa-circle {
  color: #43434379;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```