# Font Awesome Hover Issue

Tags: css, font-awesome

This question is related to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770590/change-color-when-hover-a-font-awesome-icon#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770590/change-color-when-hover-a-font-awesome-icon#_=_)

What I'm trying to achieve is the hover style on Circle behind icon.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>

.fa-circle:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvamhedx/802/

As you can see, when you go over the image, only one part of it will activate the hover effect. I guess this is because other image (flag) is on top if it.. Is there any way I could "avoid" flag icon and make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.fa-circle` is a child of `.fa-stack`, so check for the hover on the parent.

If you only want to target `.fa-circle`:

```
.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle{
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to target **all** `.fa-stack`s:

```
.fa-stack:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Or if you create your own class, it won't affect the normal behaviour:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x hover-change">
```

CSS:

```
.hover-change:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Got the same result with just `.fa-stack:hover { .. }`

Comment: @Press If that's the desired effect then that would also work. Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, the first one did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use custom classes to avoid default behavior of original definitions:

HTML :

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x customClass">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x customClassRed"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```

CSS :

```
.customClass:hover .customClassRed {
    color: red;
}
```