# How to mouseover change the color of a font-awesome 5 icon color with angular 9?

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am using (https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) and everything looks good with what the basic documentation has:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee"></fa-icon>
```

My issue is I want to have a 'hover to change color'. When I do the following:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faCoffee" [inverse]="true" class="colorchange"></fa-icon>
```

Then have CSS that says:

```
.colorchange {
}

.colorchange:hover {
color:red !important;
}
```

The CSS appears to do nothing. What is the right way to get a simple basic hover color change to work? I tried wrapping the fa-icon element with a span tag and applied a class to that and it didn't work either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25772453/6635464 : Does this answer you question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick workaround. Going through their [source](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/src/lib/icon/icon.component.ts#L31), it can be seen they use a selector class called `ng-fa-icon`. So applying `:hover` pseudo to this class should work.

```
.ng-fa-icon.hover-hightlight:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```
<fa-icon class="hover-hightlight" [icon]="['fas', 'square']"></fa-icon>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fontawesome-icon-library-7juknj)